# Android app layout help

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I'm building a screen with this design:

- a tabActivity (call it "MAIN tabhost")
- its tabwidget is at the bottom of the screen
- the content of this tabhost MAIN refers to a new TabActivity which has its tabwidget at the top of the screen and its content is a ListActivity.

I'm new with android development, and I really dont understand if its the correct approach to use one activity with other activities inside. This is currently working, but I have a couple of bugs and really don't understand how to fix them or how to start without taking a whole new approach...

[Source code (zip)](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B5Fu_YlHUgYpNzJlNGVmOTQtNmNkNC00MjRlLTk0YjItMGNkN2U4YzAzODJl&hl=es&authkey=CLG5464F)

The bugs:

1.- If the listactivity has enough items it shows over the MAIN tabwidget when scrolling
[image: while scrolling]

2.- When you stop scrolling the listview it appears behind the MAIN tabwidget [image: not scrolling]

3.- When you press a tab button on the secondary tabhost, it shows for a very short lapse the icon that is being used in the bottom tabhost (MAIN)
[image: while pressing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that if you add an bottom margin to the listView that is the height of your buttons on the bottom you will get rid of the listView going behind and in front of the buttons. I am not sure if that will fix both issues. I would try that first though.

Comment: Do you mean a layout with a fixed height? Is it possible to use a margin that prevents this problem but also adapts to different screen sizes and orientations? thanks

Comment: I mean your listView. Set the android:layout_marginBottom If you use dip (Density Independent Pixels) you should be okay. You should be able to adjust the value while in the designer until you see the shadow (The one that is currently across Asignades, Libres, and Sincronizar on the bottom) go just above them. I would also recommend setting android:layout_height to fill parent on your listView